# Perl: Is this a correct way of creating an unique array?

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures, perl-hash

I'm trying to create an unique array regardless of its original order and using no module, this's what I've come up with so far:

```
my @arr = qw(b a a c d g e f);
my %hash;
@hash{@arr}=();
say keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Since hash keys are unique, this is one idiomatic way to do it. The number of ways to accomplish the same thing are many.

You may also use a module, such as [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
print join ":", uniq qw(a a a b b c d);
```

**Output:**

```
a:b:c:d
```

Some different ways to dedupe:

```
my @arr = keys { map { $_ => 1 } qw(b a a c d g e f) };
```

The curly braces creates an anonymous hash for `keys`, the map statement creates a list of key/value pairs.

---

```
my @arr = dedupe(qw(a a b c d d e));

sub dedupe {
    my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @_;
    return keys %hash;
}
```

Same thing, but in subroutine form, and split into two lines. Note that both lists will be in a semi-random order, since hashes are unordered.

The subroutine used by `List::MoreUtils` is equally simple, and perhaps preferable, since it will preserve the order of arguments. It still uses a hash, though.

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen = ();
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just figured instead of assigning 1 or `undef` to its values, we could give each key its associated array position like this: `@hash{@arr}=(0..$#arr);` then by swapping keys and values in `%hash` we can retrieve the values based on their original order, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you could do `my @arr = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash`. However, the `uniq` sub described above is preferable, since sorting is just extra processing.

Comment: @loldop You can use a hash ref with the `keys` function. Not sure which perl version is required.

Comment: @TLP, my old perl 5.12.4 can't do it :\

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are using the correct way but there are many other ways as well to create a unique array.

see perlfaq4: [How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array?) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A unique array with no ordering a.k.a. a set. I know you said 'no module' (why?!). But if you change your mind, try [`Set::Object`](https://metacpan.org/module/Set%3a%3aObject) or [`Set::Scalar`](https://metacpan.org/module/Set%3a%3aScalar)

Comment: Thanks, because my intention is to understand the concept and not solving a problem, otherwise I have no problem with using modules.